# Java - Problem with saving buffered image to file rotates 90 degrees

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, rotation, save, bufferedimage

I've been trying to complete a method that saves Color[][] to jpg image files, however the solutions will result in the output file being rotate 90 degrees, I've tried looking for the problem but does not come obvious to me, as well as other people with similar solutions doesn't seem to have the same problems.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
private Color[][] image;  //  assume this field has already been populated

public  void saveImage() {
    BufferedImage saveImage = new BufferedImage(this.image.length, 
                                                this.image[0].length, 
                                                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    for (int row = 0; row < this.image.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < this.image[row].length; col++) {
            saveImage.setRGB(row, col, this.image[row][col].getRGB());
        }
    }

    String fName = UIFileChooser.save();
    if (fName==null){return;}

    File toFile = new File(fName+".jpg");

    try {
        ImageIO.write(saveImage,"jpg", toFile);
    }catch (IOException e){UI.println("File save error: "+e);}
}
```

thanks for the helps, it turns out I just had to flip the dimensions and x/y coordinates, below is the fixed version:

```
private Color[][] image;  //  assume this field has already been populated

public  void saveImage() {
    BufferedImage saveImage = new BufferedImage(this.image[0].length, 
                                                this.image.length, 
                                                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    for (int row = 0; row < this.image.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < this.image[row].length; col++) {
            saveImage.setRGB(col, row, this.image[row][col].getRGB());
        }
    }

    String fName = UIFileChooser.save();
    if (fName==null){return;}

    File toFile = new File(fName+".jpg");

    try {
        ImageIO.write(saveImage,"jpg", toFile);
    }catch (IOException e){UI.println("File save error: "+e);}
}
```

Comment: The symptoms indicates you simply swapped x and y (row vs column) in the `image` array...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature of the [BufferedImage.setRGB](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#setRGB(int,int,int)) method is `public void setRGB​(int x, int y, int rgb)`

X comes first, then Y. `row` equals `y` and `col` equals `x`.

So change that line to:

```
saveImage.setRGB(col, row, this.image[row][col].getRGB());
```

Comment: had to also tweak the bufferedImage to be (this.image[0].length, this.image.length,...) to make sure I have the right diamention, but otherwise thanks for the help!